# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, pycharm

при запуске кода:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
updater =       Updater(token='677329060:AAGhtwMc9fYoaNvnUs7est0vXcwf6FGkWk4') 
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
def startCommand(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Привет, давай пообщаемся?')
def textMessage(bot, update):
    response = 'Получил Ваше сообщение: ' + update.message.text
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=response)
start_command_handler = CommandHandler('start', startCommand)
text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, textMessage)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_command_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(text_message_handler)
updater.start_polling(clean=True)
updater.idle()
updater.idle()
```

программа нет выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sergey/PycharmProjects/chat/bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram'
```

у меня Python3.7 работаю в PyCharmCommunity

```
pip install python-telegram-bot сделал
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверь что `python-telegram-bot` установлен на интерпретаторе, который выбран в качестве интерпретатора проекта в PyCharm: **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter**.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда бывает достаточно переустановить модуль. При этом важно иметь в виду, что стоит очищать кэш pip3, а лучше его ещё и обновить. Лично мне помогало.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip3 uninstall python-telegram-bot
pip3 cache purge
pip3 install python-telegram-bot
```